# How do I convert a LabVIEW decimal date into a string datetime format using Python?

Tags: python, datetime, labview

I need to convert a decimal timestamp in a JSON file generated using LabVIEW into a string datetime so that I can POST it to an API I'm using. For instance, one such decimal timestamp is 3640111724.4817362; how can I do this?

EDIT: [This](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7900/en/#toc1) article from NI describes how they format their timestamps. They're starting from a nonstandard epoch (01/01/1904 00:00:00.00 UTC), so in other words, Python's interpretation is 66 years ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `datetime.fromtimestamp` from datetime and format It with `strftime` as you want:

**EDIT: subtracting 66 years to match with datetime timestamp pattern**

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 3640111724.4817362

date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
date = date - relativedelta(years=66)
print(date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output:

```
05/07/2019, 22:08:44
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct though, the timestamp I gave as an example was generated in the past, so 2085 is kind of a red flag.

Comment: So We need to know how to convert this timestamp. Please, post the timestamp with our expected output

Comment: Check the edit, the issue is a nonstandard epoch. If you subtract 66 from the year (the difference between 1970 and 1904) the timestamp turns out correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The number of seconds between 1904-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC is 2082844800, so you just need to adjust your LabView timestamp before creating your Python datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 3640111724.4817362
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp - 2082844800)
print(dt)
# 2019-05-07 22:08:44.481736
```

Comment: nice solution, since the difference doest not will change